# fast JQUERY SELECTOR for clicking

Tags: jquery, performance

Do I need to wrap class elements by an id element for a big document?

Is `$('#id').find('.class').click` 
faster than
`$('.class').click` ?

Also, I want to know.
Is `<a onclick="function()">link</a>`
faster than
`selector id link with $(selector).click`?

Comment: If my work is different classes of elements(buttons) only, do I need to wrap them or group them by an id element to get fast responsing for a clicking function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think you need to be concerned about the performance of simply using the class selector. I think the bigger issue with what you asked is that the two selectors will potentially select different elements.

The following selector:

```
$('#id').find('.class')
```

is going to find all descendant elements with the class name "class" of the element with the ID "id".

The second selector:

```
$('.class')
```

is going to find all elements with the class name "class".

Basically, it's strange to ask which is faster when they are selecting different things. The first selector is potentially a smaller subset of elements than the second (and will be faster but probably not something to tear your hair out about).

For the second part of your question, it probably depends on what you mean by "faster". If you use jQuery or JavaScript to bind an event listener, there is some time required to find the element in the DOM. But you also have the advantage of being able to delay attaching these listeners until after the important parts of your page have loaded. It's perfectly reasonable to attach an event listener through an `onclick` attribute but it really depends on the size and scope of your project. It can get very unwieldy to have all your event listener logic in your HTML files. Using selectors allows you to have better separation (among other things). I'd encourage you to do more research as there is plenty of discussion on this topic online.